# How to limit results on left join right table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel Eloquent and doing a leftJoin.

However, I need one, or two, or three  results from the right table.

How can I achieve that?

Code:

```
$registros = $registros->leftjoin('onetable','onetable.propterty_id', '=', 'second_table.id');
```

Comment: add complete code to better understanding

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; `leftJoin` joins the columns from `onetable` to each row from the results of whatever parent table; `limit` doesn't really apply to that. If you only want 1, 2 or 3 rows from the parent table, just use a `limit(3)` on the base query.

Comment: @TimLewis I need all results from parent table and only 3 from the joined table.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam the code is huge, but basically:
$registros = $registros->select(fields);
$registros = $registros->where(something);
$registros = $registros->leftJoin(that join);

Comment: Well, again, `leftJoin` doesn't add extra rows; it adds the columns from `onetable` to each row on `second_table`, so you can access `onetable.property` and `second_table.property` on each row. It sounds like you should be using `relationship`s so you can get multiple `second_table` entries on each `onetable`

Comment: @TimLewis thank's, you are right, however I searched before, and it seams that relationships do way more queries, making it slower than regular leftJoin. I guess I'll use DB, you see any problem in that?

Comment: I don't think you can use relationships with just the `\DB::` facade, so that would be a problem, yes. From my experience, there's only a slowdown when using relationships if you try to use them too often, such as `$relatedModels = $baseModel->relationship()->get();` vs `$relatedModels = $baseModel->relationship;` combined with `$baseModel = Model::with(["relationship"])->first();`, etc etc.

Comment: @TimLewis I meant without relationships. Thank you!

Comment: Ah without relationships; sorry, was wondering if you meant that. Then yes, I'm sure you can accomplish this with basic `\DB::` queries, but it would be my opinion that you're not using Laravel to it's full potential. If you're ok with that, then go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this. But you can do something similar to this

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.id','users.name as user_name','users.last_name as user_last_name', 'users.email as user_email','users.dob','user_mobile.mobile_number')
        ->join('user_mobile', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user_mobile.user_id')
                ->where('user_mobile.is_primary',1)
                ->limit(3);
        })
        ->where('users.is_admin', 0)
        ->get();
```

Note: this is not an answer, just a reference. Because I'm using same but without `>limit(3)`.

Comment: Thank you, but my hole query is already writted in eloquent, so i'll pass but thank's for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Tim Lewis, I'll use relationships, since my query is all written in eloquent.

Comment: It's probably not going to be as easy as assumed when it comes to grabbing n records per parent because if you throw a limit on the relationship, it's only going to return 3 children for all parents rather than 3 per parent like you'd expect.  I've found this resource invaluable in the past...  https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/ which helps with this problem